# Convert multiple lines of string into one string

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a code that reads each line of text from a text file and store it into a variable String s.

```
while (file.hasNext()){
     String s = file.nextLine();
}
```

When I print s, it prints out

```
what is coding
sky is green
ocean is gold
```

What can I do to so that it prints out

```
what is coding sky is green ocean is gold
```

I've tried to do s.replace("\n\r", "") and using System.lineSeparator() but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are fine.

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String line = "";
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\ExampleFile.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      // This is the key for your problem.
      line += scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` is a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String fileWithoutNewLine = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(<PATH_TO_FILE>)).replaceAll("\n", "")
```